# Issue in bringing up MQ Services in W2K8

Tags: ibm-mq

Have a PRD box of W2K8, facing issue to bring up MQ service in it.

Error  : DCOM got error "1326" and was unable to logon .\MUSR_MQADMIN in order to run the server: {4576E163-FA1A-11D1-ABB8-0004ACF79B59}                  The machine wide Default Launch and Activation security descriptor is invalid. It contains Access Control Entries with permissions that are invalid. The requested action was therefore not performed. This security permission can be corrected using the Component Services administrative tool.

Faced similar kind of issue before in same env and after adding MUSR_MQADMIN in below groups & administrators, it was working fine. Again after a month, MQ services are stopped and facing issue.
- Logon as batch job
- Logon as service
- Shut down the system
- Debug programs
- Increase quotas
- Act as part of the operating system
- Bypass traverse checking
- Replace a process level token

I have checked pemrission in DCOM and Component services as well. Everything is fine.

Kindly let me know what can be the cause of this error and will not be able to do trial and error since it is PRD env.

Answer (score 1):

Try "amqmsrvn -regserver" (you may need to change to the mq bin directory to run this). I'd also strongly suggest you look at 7.1 or higher which bins the dcom object and uses security on the service instead. If this fails, manually set the password to the musr_mqadmin account (assuming thats what in use), run dcomcnfg and change the password on the identity page.

Note if you are running on a machine in a domain, you may need to configure MQ as a domain userid which is a different set of issues

Comment: This just saved me due to a domain name change. Thank you!